# Typescript, loop through function based on values defined in array

Tags: typescript

I need to loop through a function where I defined an API call x amount of times based on the amount of values in an array. Can somebody help me with this?

```
let checkListID = "64db1d589d4a24da89794eb5";
let checkItemsArray: ["And this is a item i would like to add", "And this is another one#", "And this is the final one"];

//execute Add checkItems to checklist
  try {
    let result: any = await createCheckitemOnChecklist(flowElement, baseURL, key, token, checkListID, checkItemsArray);
  } catch (error: any) {
    let axiosMessage = (error as AxiosError).response.data.message;
    let axiosStatus = (error as AxiosError).response.status;
    await flowElement.log(LogLevel.Error, "Trello API - error " + axiosStatus + " - " + axiosMessage);
    await job.sendToData(Connection.Level.Error);
    return;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make API call for each value by iterating the array by using `for` loop.

```
let checkListID = ...
let checkItemsArray = ...

for (let item of checkItemsArray) {
    try {
      let result: any = await createCheckitemOnChecklist(flowElement, baseURL, key, token, checkListID, item);
      //Now, you can work with the result
    }
    catch (error: any) {
        ...
    }
}
```